# Standard(or best looking) SFINAE implementation for stream opearator overload

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I have the following code

```
template<typename S, typename T, bool h = is_class< decltype(T::children)>::value >
    S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t )
{
    return s;
}
```

that will overload the `operator<<` when a class have a member variable named children.

What is the standard way or do there exist a better looking way for making the function fail when `is_class< decltype(T::children)>` fails.

I cannot use the return type or an argument because this is operator overloading.

Comment: `static_assert` or rely on the compiler to pick up the error.

Comment: Bad duck typing - `T::children` is too general

Comment: @CaptainObvlious that is a horrible idea, as `operator<<` will break on completely unrelated types.

Comment: @Hans why overload on `S&` and not `std::ostream&`?  Seems like a bad idea to overload with *anything* on the left hand side.

Comment: When it fails, you'd get "no match for `operator<<`", isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @Yakk ostream will not be the only receiver.

Comment: @Barry- Sorry, I forgot to mention this is SFINAE- it may not be obvious

Comment: @Hansvesselgård It's in the title. That doesn't answer the question though - the point of SFINAE is to remove candidates from the overload set - is that not sufficient?

Comment: Using an unnamed type is common. Like `template< typename S, typename T, typename = decltype(T::children) >`

Comment: @Hansvesselgård except the above code allows `int` to be a receiver.  Seems pretty crazy.

Comment: @Yakk- I have not showed the code that is irrelevant for the question- but it will iterate the tuple and << it to the receiver. If the tuple have anything that do not work with the receiver it will fail anyway.

Comment: @  Dieter Lücking I will take care of that with other controls. I have not showed code that is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @  sp2danny  thank you very much.

Comment: Why can't you use the return type for SFINAE?

Comment: T.C. good question. While going over the reasons I thought of doing something like typename enable_if<is_class< decltype(T::children)>, S> . That is what you are thinking of- right? Thank you for your question- it made me rethink my assumptions.

Comment: Me, I do `template<typename S, typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_class< decltype(T::children) >{}> > S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t ) { return s; }`, or use `class=void_t<decltype(T::children)>` or whatever.

Comment: I ended up doing  template<typename STREAM_RECEIVER_TYPE, typename CHILDREN_CONTAINER_TYPE  >
 enable_if_t<
   traits::is_sequence< decltype(CHILDREN_CONTAINER_TYPE::children)>::value,
 STREAM_RECEIVER_TYPE&> 
  operator<<(STREAM_RECEIVER_TYPE& streamReceiver, const CHILDREN_CONTAINER_TYPE& childrenContainer)
  {
   for_each(childrenContainer.children, [&](const auto& child)
   {
    streamReceiver << child;
   });
  
  return streamReceiver;
  }
}

Comment: It was weird why I assumed that using the return type would not work- I think I forgot that enable_if can output whatever you want. Thank you very much again :)